# Inner product and norm in $H^1_{per}([0,L])$

Tags: normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces, inner-products, periodic-functions

Let $L>0$ fixed. Consider the space
$$\mathcal{P}:=C_{per}^{\infty}([0,L])=\{f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\; ; \; f \: \text{is infinitely differentiable and periodic with period}\: L\}.$$

Consider the Sobolev Space $H^1_{per}([0,L])$. This space can be interpreted as the set of $f \in \mathcal{P}'$ such that
$$f, f' \in L^2_{per}([0,L]),$$
with norm
$$||f||_{H^1_{per}}=(||f||^2_{L^2_{per}}+||f'||^2_{L^2_{per}})^{\frac{1}{2}}, \; \forall \; f \in H^1_{per}([0,L]), \tag{1}$$
where
$$L^2_{per}([0,L])=\{f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \; ; \; f \: \text{is   periodic with period} \; L \; \text{and} \; f|_{[0,L]} \in L^2([0,L])\} $$
with inner product
$$(f,g)_{L^2_{per}}=\int_0^L f(x) \overline{g(x)}\; dx, \; \forall \; f,g \in L^2_{per}([0,L]).$$

**Question 1.** I can rewrite $ (1) $ as
$$||f||_{H^1_{per}}=(||f||^2_{L^2_{per}}+||\nabla f||^2_{L^2_{per}})^{\frac{1}{2}}?$$

**Question 2.** Similarly to Sobolev Space $H_0^1(\Omega)$, with $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded, using the Poincaré Inequality can I define a norm in $H^1_{per}([0,L])$ by
$$||f||_{H^1}:=||\nabla f||_{L^2_{per}}, \forall \; f\in H^1_{per}([0,L])?$$

And in this case a inner product in $H^1_{per}([0,L])$ by
$$(f,g)_{H_1}=(\nabla f, \nabla g)_{L^2}, \; \forall \; f,g \in H^1_{per}([0,L])?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes, because
$$\nabla f=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \right)$$ where $n$  is the space dimension. In your case, $\nabla f=\frac{\partial f} {\partial x_1}$. Since in dimension $1$ you have only one direction you can write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=\frac{d f}{dt}=f'$.

As for question $2$, for the Poincaré inequality to be valid, you need more hypotheses about the function $f$, for example, that the mean of it is $0$. So, for function $f \in H^{1}_{per}([0,L])$ where Poincaré's inequality fails, you will not be able to prove that $(\nabla f, \nabla f)=0 \Rightarrow f=0$

Comment: If $\int_0^L f(x) \; dx=0$ then the Poincaré inequality holds? So, for this class of functions $f$ can I define the inner product $(\cdot, \cdot )_{H_1}$?

Comment: Yes, if $u \in H_{per}^{1}([0,L)]$ and $\int_{0}^{L} f(x)  dx=0$ then the Poincaré's inequality holds, that is, $\|f\|_{L^{2}_{per}}^{2} \leq C \| \nabla f\|_{L^{2}_{per}}^{2}$. Thus, $\|\nabla f\|=0 \Rightarrow f=0$. The other properties of the inner product are easily checked. Moreover, the topology induced by $H_{per}^{1}([0,L])$ in $M=\{u \in H_{per}^{1}([0,L]): \int_{0}^{L} f(x) dx=0\}$ coincides with the topology induced by the inner product $(\nabla(\cdot),\nabla(\cdot))_{L^2_{per}}$.

Comment: Moreover, I think it is possible to prove that $M$ is a closed subspace of $H_{per}^{1}([0,L])$ consequently, a complete subspace.

Comment: Very good. Thanks Victor!